# Как открыть страницу JSP заданного размера из сервлета?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

из формы по submit передаю управление сервлету. Сервлет что то делает и откравает другую страницу JSP. 
Проблема в том, что эту новую страницу надо открыть в уменьшенном размере. Например 600 на 600. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит в уменьшенном размере? Нужно открыть на моб. телефоне? Или  открыть в модальном окне?

Comment: Нет на обычном компьютере. Необходимо открыть окно не во весь экран а в половину. Желательно без меню и тулбаров.

Comment: Если можно в модальном это вообще здорово. Но как? Из сервлета могу только перенаправить на страницу  requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Error.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: Вот ссылка [как сделать модальное окно](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) + [пример](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)